# How to avoid parent POM issue in Eclipse for a Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have been working with multi-module Maven project, but in my workspace I use only child-modules, not their parent. In each `pom.xml` for each Maven module I have:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.contentbus.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>modules-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
```

It is possible to do "maven clean", "maven install" etc. in Eclipse, but Maven reports red errors in "Markers" window, and "red crosses" on the modules in Project Explorer. I successfully avoided it by following this pattern: set in `\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs` a property `eclipse.m2.problem.notCoveredMojoExecution=ignore`. But, I need to avoid this issue on the module level somehow, but inside the code (in project files), not in Eclipse options. Are there any possible ways to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What errors do you get in the markers window?

Comment: The error is: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration ...

Comment: Changing plugins' preferences in the `.metadata` folder manually is a bad idea. Have you looked at [the 327 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plugin+execution+not+covered+by+lifecycle+configuration)?

Comment: One of @GeroldBroser's links must help :-p - I think your error has nothing to do with parent/child pom issues, but rather that there are plugins in there in either one that Eclipse doesn't know how to handle.  Often, right-clicking on the error row in the Markers window will give you options for fixing it, of which the best one is to download an Eclipse helper do deal with that plugin...

Comment: Please show the full log output instead of snippets...